# While running arch install iso, how do i tab over to a fresh commandline? And how do i get back to the original window?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, zsh

I used to be able to run multiple commands simultaneously by tabbing between command lines. Kind of like a web browser but hotkeys only.

How do I do this again? Nothing useful came up on several searches.

The install iso uses zsh instead of bash.

Comment: Are you asking how to *switch between virtual consoles*?

Comment: Regarding @JaromandaXs's comment, to switch between virtual console you have to use: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Fn`  where `Fn` may be `F1`, `F2`, etc. . In my case only the virtual consoles from `F1` to `F7` are active. If I want to use another one I have to activate it via systemd: `sudo systemctl start getty@tty9.service`. And to switch to `console 9` you can press: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F9` or you can use the command: `sudo chvt 9`